# How to sum value class only element display visible jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table, I want sum all Column only for visible Row's

This is my code

```
var plus = $('tr').css('display') != 'none');
var sum = 0;

$('.price', plus).each(function () {
      var value = $(this).text(). replace(/[^0-9]/, ' ');
      sum += parseInt(value);
});
$('result').text(sum);
```

Comment: Let's count brackets together `$(1'tr')2.css(3'display')4 != 'none')5;`

Comment: Also, what selector is `'result'` ? You mean `'#result'`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve via the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

In your case, `td.price:visible` could be used to select `td` elements with class `price` that are `:visible`. The query result could then be iterated with `each()` to perform the summation:

```js
var sum = 0;

/* Select all td with class, and that are visible */
$('td.price:visible').each(function() {

  /* Parse content of visible td with Number.parseInt */
  var value = Number.parseInt($(this).text());
  if (!Number.isNaN(value)) {
  
    /* If value is a number, add it to the total */
    sum += value
  }

});

/* Fix selector */
$('.result').text(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td><td class="plus">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td><td class="plus" style="display:none;">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td><td class="plus">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Result</td><td class="result">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `<span class="price">15 $</span>` and some parent `<tr>` can be `display:none;` - you could filter all the `.price` elements whose `offsetParent` property is not *null*.
You could also create a function to convert currency to Number and use it like:

```js
const currencyToNumber = currency => +(currency.replace(/[^\d.-]+/g,''));
const calculatePriceList = () => {
  const TR_visible = [...document.querySelectorAll('.price')].filter(el => el.offsetParent);
  const result = TR_visible.reduce((n, el) => n + currencyToNumber(el.textContent), 0);
  document.querySelector('#result').textContent = result;
}

calculatePriceList(); // Do it!
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="priceList">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Item 1</td><td><span class="price">15 $</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2</td><td><span class="price">10 $</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="none"><td>Item 3</td><td><span class="price">50 $</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="none"><td>Item 4</td><td><span class="price">50 $</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 5</td><td><span class="price">3,100.00 $</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td><span id="result"></span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```